# In C# How to clear cache of a REST service response?

Tags: c#, rest, model-view-controller

I have a MVC Application that calls a Web Service to get the status of the the Web Service. But I discovered that my application server stores the response in a cache and so won't update the web service status on future requests? How can I force it to always get update the status?

```
[DataContract]
public class AppStatus
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ServiceAddr;
    [DataMember]
    public string AppName;
    [DataMember]
    public string Database;
    [DataMember]
    public TimeSpan RunningTime;
    [DataMember]
    public string VersionInfo;
    [DataMember]
    public string TotalMemory;
    [DataMember]
    public double ResponseTime;
}

public AppStatus Status()
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
    var strDBStatus = GetDBStatus();
    int count = 0;
    bool numConverted = Int32.TryParse(strDBStatus, out count);


    AppStatus status = new AppStatus() 
    { 
        ServiceAddr = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.OriginalString,
        VersionInfo = fvi.FileVersion,
        AppName = fvi.ProductName,
        TotalMemory = FormatBytes(GC.GetTotalMemory(false)),
        RunningTime = DateTime.Now - Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime,
        Database = numConverted && count > 0? "OK" : strDBStatus
    };
    status.ResponseTime = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
    return status;
}
```

Here's how I'm currently calling the service:

```
public class StatusController : Controller
{
    // GET: Status
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        string srvAddr =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceAddr"]; 
        try
        {
            var chan = WSCom.GetClientChannel();
            var srvStatus = chan.Status();
            ViewBag.SrvStatus = srvStatus;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogException(e);

            var srvStatus = new AppStatus(){
                ServiceAddr =   srvAddr,
                AppName = "Service Error"
            };
            ViewBag.SrvStatus = srvStatus;
        }

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
        AppStatus _appStatus = new AppStatus()
        {
            ServiceAddr = HttpContext.Request.RawUrl,
            VersionInfo = fvi.FileVersion,
            AppName = fvi.ProductName,
            TotalMemory = FormatBytes(GC.GetTotalMemory(false)),
            RunningTime = DateTime.Now - Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime
        };
        _appStatus.ResponseTime = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
        ViewBag.AppStatus = _appStatus;
        return View();
    }

    private string FormatBytes(long bytes)
    {
        string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB" };

        int order = 0;
        while (bytes >= 1024 && order + 1 < sizes.Length)
        {
            order++;
            bytes = bytes / 1024;
        }

        // Adjust the format string to your preferences. For example "{0:0.#}{1}" would
        // show a single decimal place, and no space.
        string result = String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", bytes, sizes[order]);
        return result;
    }
}

    // Get client channel
    public static IService GetClientChannel()
    {
        var srvAddr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceAddr"].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(srvAddr))
            throw new NullReferenceException();

        Uri uri = new Uri(srvAddr);
        WebChannelFactory<IService> cf =
            new WebChannelFactory<IService>(uri);

        IService tc = cf.CreateChannel();

        if (tc == null)
            Trace.TraceError("Unable to connect service address ( " + srvAddr + ")");

        return tc;
    }
```

Comment: are you hosting it in IIS? I have a feeling its the server caching rather than the client

Comment: What is the `WSCom.GetClientChannel()` implemented with? Assuming this is implemented over HTTP, can you provide a request-response pair for the problem scenario?

Comment: I added the code for GetClientChannel() and yes it's hosted in IIS

Comment: It looks like it's doing some sort of cache on the Web Service. When I run the application from another server and use the same Web Service URL it does the same thing. When I run both the service and app locally it updates the service response correctly.

Comment: Update: I did some more testing and monitoring of the request-reponse. I noticed it is updating the RunningTime but not always the Response Time. After the first call it often comes back with 0 ms for the Response Time for the Service Status.